# How to configure FishEye to connect to an Jira server using SSL?

Tags: ssl-certificate, java, jira, fisheye

I have a jira server running at https://jira.example.com/ and everything with it is fine. It is a real certificate, not a self-signed cert. I am trying to turn up a FishEye server and I'd like to use the Jira integration during the initial setup wizard. The problem is, the jira integration always fails with the following.

```
Could not retrieve manifest from https://jira.example.com.
Please check the JIRA Server URL, and ensure it is JIRA 4.3 or later.
```

After reading through the documentation for a while I stumbled on the setting for enabling remote API calls in Jira, so I did that, but still have the issue.

I found the log file on the server and took a look at that, it has some more details (I'm omitting the full stack trace because I assume it isn't really very useful, and is several hundred lines):

```
2015-10-05 22:29:09,798 ERROR - Failed to retrieve manifest from https://jira.example.com
com.atlassian.applinks.spi.manifest.ManifestNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

This seems to suggest that this is an SSL thing. I also ran across [this article](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9387/could-not-retrieve-manifest-from-httpsjira.onlifehealth.com.-please-check-the-jira-server-url-and-ensure-it-is-jira-4.3-or-later) which seems to suggest that it is fairly easy to fix, but doesn't supply any details about what the fix is.

How can I fix this SSLHandshakeException?

Comment: Did you contact Atlassian support?

Comment: @EEAA, I have not. They don't support SSL anyway, and this looks and sounds like a pure java/ssl issue to me.